# Sonar error in database connection with Mysql

Tags: sonarqube

We suddenly started getting error into sonar  any idean what it can be

```
Caused by: org.sonar.api.database.DatabaseException: Cannot open connection to database: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.)
    at org.sonar.api.database.AbstractDatabaseConnector.testConnection(AbstractDatabaseConnector.java:182) [sonar-plugin-api-2.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.database.AbstractDatabaseConnector.start(AbstractDatabaseConnector.java:94) [sonar-plugin-api-2.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.database.JndiDatabaseConnector.start(JndiDatabaseConnector.java:65) [JndiDatabaseConnector.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [na:1.6.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [na:1.6.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [na:1.6.0_21]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [na:1.6.0_21]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) [picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1225) [commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880) [commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.sonar.server.database.JndiDatabaseConnector.getConnection(JndiDatabaseConnector.java:154) [JndiDatabaseConnector.class:na]
    at org.sonar.api.database.AbstractDatabaseConnector.testConnection(AbstractDatabaseConnector.java:178) [sonar-plugin-api-2.2.jar:na]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the mysql error logs and/or network connectivity.

99% chance is anything but sonar. :)

Comment: I am not sure where to check mysql logs , as it is pr server so i have limited access